# Robot Framework how to create dictionary with unknown number of keys?

Tags: python, robotframework

How to create dictionary when keyword does not know how many args?

I wrote below code, And I want dictionary

```
${aaaaa} = {'A':'aaa', 'B':'bbb', 'C':'ccc'}
${bbbbb} = {'A':'aaa', 'B':'bbb', 'C':'ccc', 'D': 'ddd'}
```

Where should I change My Keyword?

```
*** Settings ***
Library       Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Test AAA
    ${aaaaa}    My Keyword    A=aaa    B=bbb    C=ccc
    ${bbbbb}    My Keyword    A=aaa    B=bbb    C=ccc    D=ddd

*** Keywords ***
My Keyword
    [Arguments]    @{args}
    ${resp}    Create Dictionary    ${args}
    [Return]    ${resp}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify "when keyword does not know how many keywords"? It's currently a little difficult to determine what you are asking for.

Comment: You could use a dictionary comprehension to grab keys and values by index.

Comment: thanks. I parse string and resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing to creating a dictionary, just use the `create dictionary` keyword. However, if you want to create your own keyword which takes a variable number of keyword arguments, use a dictionary as the argument:

```
My Keyword
    [Arguments]  &{args}

    [Return]  ${args}
```

This keyword will return a dictionary made up of the keys and values passed in to the keyword